# Is this sentence correct? "Does anyone have any idea what this tattoo means?"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it "Does anyone have any idea what this tattoo **means**?" or "Does anyone have any idea what this tattoo **mean**?"

Comment: You have to find out whether **tatoo** is singular or plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second statement seems to be wrong, tattoo is a singular things. It should be "means". Plural should be tattoos if you need to use it. So it should either be 'tattoos mean' or 'tattoo means'.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but what do you mean by both statements seem to be wrong at different places? So you're saying that out of the two sentences above, "tattoo means" is correct right?

Comment: Oh ya. Only the second statement is wrong. I will update the answer accordingly. I have overlooked. Thanks.